# Memory leaks with QDataStream and QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt

Have the structure:

```cpp
struct BrokerParameters : Header {
    QByteArray name;
    quint16 port{};
    BrokerParameters();
    BrokerParameters(QByteArray name, quint16 port);
    BrokerParameters(const BrokerParameters&) = delete;
    bool operator==(const BrokerParameters& other) const;
};
```

which I need to pass through TCP Socket, so, I overloaded operators `>>` and `<<` to use it with `QDataStream`:

```cpp
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &stream, const BrokerParameters &data) {
    stream.setVersion(DATASTREAM_VERSION);
    stream << data.name;
    stream << data.port;
    return stream;
}

QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &stream, BrokerParameters &data) {
    stream.setVersion(DATASTREAM_VERSION);
    stream >> data.name;  // <<<< memory leak here
    stream >> data.port;
    return stream;
}
```

On one side I send it via `QTcpSocket` (which is `io` here)

```cpp
template <typename PacketType>
bool writeToIoDevice(const PacketType& object, QIODevice* io) {
    QDataStream stream(io);
    stream << object;
    return stream.status() == QDataStream::Ok;
}
```

and receive on the other side with two functions:

```cpp
template <typename PacketType>
std::shared_ptr<const PacketType> loadFromStream(QDataStream& stream,
                                                 IoReadType type = IoReadType::DEFAULT) {
    stream.startTransaction();
    auto result = std::make_unique<PacketType>();
    stream >> *result;
    if (type == IoReadType::ROLLBACK_AFTER) {  // restore stream to the initial state after reading
        if (stream.status() != QDataStream::Status::Ok) result = nullptr;
        stream.rollbackTransaction();
    } else if (!stream.commitTransaction()) {
        return { nullptr };
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename PacketType>
std::shared_ptr<const PacketType> loadFromIoDevice(QIODevice* io,
                                                   IoReadType type = IoReadType::DEFAULT) {
    QDataStream stream(io);
    return loadFromStream<PacketType>(stream, type);
}
```

By analyzing the code with Valgrind on the *receiving* side I get `blocks are definitely lost in loss record...` on the line `stream >> data.name;` (marked it above).

I tried to read it as a raw char*:

```cpp
    char* name = nullptr;
    stream >> name;
    data.name = QByteArray(name);
    delete[] name;
```

but now have the memory leak in line `data.name = ...`. Why? How should I properly use `QByteArray` with `QDataStream`?

Comment: Does it work with `std::string`? Like `std::string name; stream >> name; data.name = QByteArray(name.c_str())`?

Comment: @kiner_shah no, `QDataStream` does not support `std::` containers

Comment: Then do something like `char* name = new char[1024]; stream >> name; data.name = QByteArray(name); delete[] name;`

Comment: Does this `BrokerParameters` struct have an overloaded copy constructor? Because your `loadFromStream` function copies the `unique_ptr` to a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Botje no, but I deleted copy constructor. Can it be the problem? P.S> Updated the structure in the first message

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was with the way I closed the application. I did it by pressing `ctrl->c` and these memory leaks occurred because of that. If application is stopped correctly, Valgrind shows no memory issues at all.